# JavaScript Object Reference Error this Window Object

Tags: javascript, this

I am making some JavaScript functions and trying to be better about my constructors and keywords.

I know that the `this` keyword in JavaScript defaults to the  `Window` object if invocated in certain ways.

However, I am getting a value for a variable `top` as the `Window` object in my console, despite the fact that when I assign something like `var self = this` it is always in a function that I have used `.call()` or `new` to assign the scope of `this` to not be the `Window` object.

Here is my problem area:

```
 function assignTransformCoordinates(deltaX, deltaY) {
           var imgRect = self.childElements.img.getBoundingClientRect();
           console.log(vpRect,imgRect,deltaX,deltaY,transform.y);
               top = transform.y + deltaY,
               left = transform.x + deltaX;
               console.log(deltaY,transform.y);
               //**above log gives me 6 and 0**
               if (vpRect.top < imgRect.top + deltaY && vpRect.bottom > imgRect.bottom + deltaY) {
                transform.y = top;
                console.log("shift top! " + top);
                //**above log gives me top as [object Window]
            }
       }
```

I don't understand why `top` becomes `[object Window]` just a few lines below its declaration as (when evaluated in the logged example) `6 + 0`. I am thinking even though `transform.y` evaluates in the log as `0` that when I add it deltaY (`6`) it is doing something that is not arithmetic?

`transform` is instantiated like this: `transform = Transform.parse()`

which does this:

```
var Transform = function (x, y, scale) {
          this.x = parseFloat(x);
          this.y = parseFloat(y);
          this.scale = parseFloat(scale);
      };

      Transform.parse = function () {
             return new Transform(1,1,1); //example values
      };
```

Because it uses the `new` keyword, I don't think the `this` in the Transform constructor should be `object Window`.

So really, where is this coming from? Why is `transform.y` seemingly 0 and then it turns to this weird object when added with 6? Does `0` stand for some other value?

Please give any suggestions of pointers for how I can track down where this Window object is being assigned.

Comment: Two syntax errors.  In the first code block, `top = transform.y + deltaY,` should end with a semicolon, not a comma.  In the second code block there are two `return`s in the `Transform.parse` function.  Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to analyze your code.  Also see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for a description of how Javascript's `this` keyword behaves.

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons okay the last one was not in my actual code :P

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons fixed comma and doesn't change result

Comment: You don't declare *top*, so it's resolved along the entire scope chain. In browsers, there is a default [*window.top* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) so that's what you try to assign a value to. It's not writeable, so the assignment doesn't change its value. Anyway, just declare *top* (and *left*) so `var top = ... , left = ...;`.

Comment: oh wow I'm so foolish thanks @RobG